# Copy a FileInputStream to a file, either as text or as a string of bytes

Tags: java, io

I have written a small program that reads input from a text file and then writes this output to a text file. The method contains a switch which decides whether to output to the file as text or as a literal string of the bytes. How could I refactor this code to only include a single if statement block instead of two to switch between these two modes? I am also interested if there is a more optimal way of writing this code overall.

I have tried to create just one switch at the beginning of the code which would change the output files from output-text-txt to output-bytes.txt (which are located in the resources folder) as well as changing the writing method (whether it writes the integer or string literals). I encounter difficulty when I need to write the bytes because the method asks for either an integer or a string and I am not sure how I would change these writing methods with just one if statement at the beginning of the code (due to it asking for int c as a parameter)

```
public class ByteStreamTest {

    private static File input;
    private static File output;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        new ByteStreamTest().write(true);
        new ByteStreamTest().write(false);     
    }

    public ByteStreamTest() {}

    public void write(boolean asText) {

        input = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("input.txt").getPath());

        if (asText) {
            output = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("output-text.txt").getPath());
        } else {
            output = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("output-bytes.txt").getPath());
        }

        FileInputStream in = null;
        FileWriter fw = null;

        try {

            in = new FileInputStream(input);
            fw = new FileWriter(output);

            int c;

            while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
                if (asText) {
                    fw.write(c);                
                } else {
                     fw.write(String.valueOf(c) + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                }
            }

            in.close();
            fw.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This isn't really a question that has to do with the functionality of the code, I am simply interested in refactoring the code to include as little if statements as possibly optimizing it further.

Comment: In order to give you proper advice for refactoring, we need to understand your real-world use cases. Why would you want to output a string of bytes, and how do you decide which mode to use?

Comment: @200_success There is no real world case. I am doing this only for my own information. I would like to practice reading and writing from files and also how to manipulate byte data. The entire purpose of this program is to provide a function that can read a file, and write those file contents to a new file, with a switch that allows me to choose whether it writes the text or the string representation of the bytes to the output file.

Comment: You could apply the *strategy* design pattern. Define an abstract class with the abstract method `write()`. Then write two implementations:  MyTextWriter and MyBinaryWriter. Now you only need one if statement to decide which class to instantiate.

Comment: @AedvaldTseh Instead of subclassing and overriding, the transformation should be implemented as a separate component (interface), which is injected into the ByteStreamTest class.

Answer (score 3):

Please note I am not an expert in Java, I do know something about object oriented programming.

Java is an object oriented programming language. To write good object oriented programs it's best to keep 5 programming principles in mind. Together these 5 principles are called [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) programming. The 5 programming principles are

- The [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)
- The [Open-closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle)
- The [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)
- The [Interface segregation principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle)
- The [Dependency inversion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle)

The single responsibility principle states:

> that every module, class, or function should have responsibility over a single part of the functionality provided by the software, and that responsibility should be entirely encapsulated by that module, class or function.

This program violates the single responsibility principle in 2 ways, first the function `main()` is included in the class and second the `write()` function is too complex (does too much) and should be simplified.

The function `write()` might be better named `copy()`. It should do only one thing, which is copy the input file to the output file. There could be 2 `copy()` functions, one for `text` and one for `strings`. The decision on which way to write to the output file should be outside the `copy` functions.

Opening and closing the files should be outside the `write` function. The program should only open the input file once and possibly reset it to the beginning the second time.

The `ByteStreamTest` constructor could open the input file.
There could be a Boolean member of the `ByteStreamTest` class that is either public and gets modified by `main()` or private with accessor functions.

Comment: A third S-violation is that the "copier" is also responsible for transforming the incoming data into the desired output format. This should be fixed by creating an interface with which an input byte (int) can be converted to a desired output bytes and passing an implementation of that interface to the copier instead of the boolean flag. This would also fulfill the desire to avoid if-statements.

Answer (score 1):

Opening this in an IDE already shows a bunch of problems to fix.

- `input` and `output` can be local variables, in fact this is all
  rather procedural, so it makes sense that the containing class is just
  to contain the main method anyway.
- The empty constructor is pointless.
- The `args` parameter is written weirdly, it should be `String[] args`.
- `throws Exception` doesn't do anything.
- The catch-all block for `Exception` doesn't even catch all exceptions
  as the input and output files are opened outside of it.
- Initialisation to `null` is the same as not writing it explicitly.
- `String.valueOf(c)` doesn't do much, `c` itself is just fine for
  `c + "some string"` already.
- `getResource` can return `null` - here it's probably to ignore that.

And after some more manual inspection:

- Don't call `close`, use a [try-with block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).
- Perhaps only get the line separator once, not in a loop (although
  that's *probably* optimised away).
- The `while` loop is very inefficient, but that's probably not a
  concern here, so I'm not sure what to recommend.  Maybe that the
  string concatenation can be avoided by going for two method calls
  instead.  You'd have to profile it regardless if that makes any
  measurable difference at all.
- `boolean` arguments are easy to get wrong (that's why some IDEs show
  the name of argument at call sites.  That can be avoided by using a
  [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), aka `new ...().asText(true).write()` or something
  along those lines.

```
public class ByteStreamTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new ByteStreamTest().write(true);
        new ByteStreamTest().write(false);
    }

    private File open(String filename) {
        return new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(filename).getPath());
    }

    private void write(boolean asText) throws IOException {
        File input = open("input.txt");
        File output = open(asText ? "output-text.txt" : "output-bytes.txt");

        try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(input);
             FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(output)) {
            String separator = System.getProperty("line.separator");

            int c;
            while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
                fw.write(c);
                if (!asText) {
                    fw.write(separator);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Anyway, as an exercise how to avoid `if`s it can always be rewritten in
terms of two classes where one class does the `true` branch, the other
the `false` branch.  That also means that suddenly there's a big
increase in code to read for nothing much of a benefit.

For a nicer to use API, I'd imagine something like this would make way
more sense though:

```
public class ByteStreamTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        copy(open("input.txt"), open("output-text.txt"), true)
        copy(open("input.txt"), open("output-bytes.txt"), false)
    }

    private static void copy(File input, File output, boolean asText) throws IOException {...}
    private static File open(String filename) {...}
}
```

It's all procedural after all.  Secondly as was already said, `copy`
makes more sense and `open` can use
`ByteStreamTest.class.getClassLoader()...` without having to actually
create an object of the class.

(Why is it writing to the locations from the class loader?  That
wouldn't work at all if this was running from a JAR, wouldn't it?)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can get rid of the `if`. I'd leverage a `Function mapToOutput`, with value either `x -> x` (no change) or `x -> String.valueOf(x) + System.getProperty("line.separator")` (your other logic).

Keep in mind that it may not actually be desirable to do this, though - it adds complexity, while only saving you a little repetition. I've done it below, and also added some comments on the rest of your code:

```
public class ByteStreamTest {

    private static File input;
    private static File output;
    private static Function mapToOutput;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        new ByteStreamTest().write(true);
        new ByteStreamTest().write(false);     
    }

    public ByteStreamTest() {}

    public void write(boolean asText) {

        input = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("input.txt").getPath());

        if (asText) {
            output = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("output-text.txt").getPath());
            mapToOutput = x -> x; // could replace with Function.identity()
        } else {
            output = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("output-bytes.txt").getPath());
            mapToOutput = x -> String.valueOf(x) + System.getProperty("line.separator");
        }
```

The block above is effectively setting the *parameters* for the block below:

```
        FileInputStream in = null;
        FileWriter fw = null;
```

These could go in a try-with-resources, e.g. `try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(input); FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(output)) { ...`

```
        try {

            in = new FileInputStream(input);
            fw = new FileWriter(output);
```

I'm a big fan of either `fr` and `fw` (in this case you're not using a `FileReader`, so the point is moot), **or** `in` and `out`, but not the two mixed together :)

```
            int c;
```

Why `c`? It's not a great name.

```
            while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
                fw.write(mapToOutput.apply(c));
            }

            in.close();
            fw.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

It would be good to have a `finally` block to close your resources, or else create them in a try-with-resources. This try-catch *does not* guarantee your resources will be closed.

```
    }
}
```